# $\pi\left(\left(n+m\right)^2\right) - \pi\left(n^2\right) \ge 2 \cdot m$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, conjectures

**Conjecture**

For $n \ge 1 $ , $m \ge 1$

$\pi\left(\left(n+m\right)^2\right) - \pi\left(n^2\right) \ge 2 \cdot m$

where $\pi\left(n\right)$ is the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) .

---

Does this conjecture have a name ?  Do you know of anywhere in the literature where this issue is investigated ?

---

**P.S.**

I know that there are similar conjectures like [Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture) and [Brocard's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_conjecture) .

Comment: Legendre's conjecture essentially says that [A014085](https://oeis.org/A014085)$(n)\ge1$. You say that it is $\ge2$.

Comment: Am I understanding this wrong? If both $n$ and $n+m$ are primes then $\pi ((n+m)^2)=\pi (n^2)=2$